# Unable to connect - mailchimp URI

Tags: laravel

I am not able redirect back to my application after login to mailchimp using laravel/socialite. As laravel 5 not suppoting mailchimp I am using

"socialiteproviders/mailchimp": "^1.0" package

My redirec_uri in mailchimp app is : http://127.0.0.1:8000/something/something

I am using same redirect uri in .env also

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the local address, it's not reachable outside your computer

Answer (score 0):

The Mailchimp API uses OAuth2 which is using an redirect uri as parameter.
You have to add the redirect_uri parameter to your API request.

https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/oauth2/

In Socialite, you have to add the parameter to the config/services.php array.

```
'github' => [
  'client_id' => 'your-github-app-id',
  'client_secret' => 'your-github-app-secret',
  'redirect' => 'http://your-callback-url'
],
```